# How do I programmatically show or hide the Outlook envelope icon?

Tags: windows, outlook

For example, how do I show or hide the Outlook envelope icon from an Outlook Rule?

The envelope icon option is set by going to:

- Tools -> Options...
- E-mail Options
- Advanced E-mail Options
- Show an envelope icon in the notification area

The reason why I say programmatically is because none of the standard Rule actions apply. (The "Clear the message flag" action doesn't seem to work. Also, there's no "Set the message flag" action.)

This means that the solution will probably be in the form of a VBA script, Add-in or custom action. As a last resort, I'll write my own task bar notification.

In the documentation, I found IMsoEnvelope, but that is only for sending email from other Office applications.

Comment: I asked about this same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378313/need-a-vb-script-to-display-outlook-new-mail-icon

Comment: @rayndev You mention Rules, which event are you hoping to capture when showing/hiding the envelope?

Comment: new mail that stays in the inbox - ie doesn't get moved to another folder... since all other rules "stop rule processing", then this final rule only gets when a new message stays in the inbox.

Answer (score 2):

The action is "Clear the message flag"