# Creating systray icon with vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I can only use vbscript on this computer, I would like to display an icon in the systray.

I found a similar question and an answer using VBA.
[Display new mail icon in Windows taskbar using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378313/display-new-mail-icon-in-windows-taskbar-using-vbscript)

There is also this code from Microsoft which explains how to do it from VBA
[How to use the System Tray directly from Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/176085?p=1)

These solution work with the following API call

```
Public Declare Function Shell_NotifyIcon Lib "shell32" _
      Alias "Shell_NotifyIconA" _
      (ByVal dwMessage As Long, pnid As NOTIFYICONDATA) As Boolean
```

The problem is how to create the user-defined type in vbscript.

```
Public Type NOTIFYICONDATA
       cbSize As Long
       hwnd As Long
       uId As Long
       uFlags As Long
       uCallBackMessage As Long
       hIcon As Long
       szTip As String * 64
End Type
```

VBScript only has a "variant" for all variable, there isn't a TYPE statement to create the kind of thing  `Shell_NotifyIcon` needs.

I have read somewhere the possibility of using a class statement.

Perhaps something like this ?

```
Class NOTIFYICONDATA
 cbSize 
 hwnd 
 uId 
 uFlags 
 uCallBackMessage 
 hIcon 
 szTip(64)
End Class
```

However I think my syntax is wrong or that the class object doesn't work that way. Or maybe, since each component of that class is a variant instead of the type that `Shell_NotifyIcon` expect, it won't work ?

I don't mind using a ugly has to force vbscript engine into making the proper memory object to use the API call, if there is any way ?

(In a later episode, if I manage to create a systray icon, I would like to get click events from the icon and display a context menu (vbscript lacks a form object to create user interfaces, except for the extremely limited forms from the HTA objects which I rather not use))

Comment: Unlike VBA, you cannot call Windows APIs directly in VBScript. The only way you could do it is by writing a COM wrapper that performs the same function and call that instead.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [@Lankymart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516696/creating-systray-icon-with-vbscript#comment70245459_41516696), VBScript can't use Windows APIs directly. You could write a COM wrapper that exposes particular interfaces to VBScript, but then you could just as well implement your whole application in VB6 or VB.net.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I use vbscript is that my work computer does not have admin access, so installing VB6 or .net is not an option. That's why I turned to vbscript in the first place.  I also tried the method in the following URL however something went wrong as when I ran the final vbs file I got "ACtiveX component can't create object 'WindowsScriptingObject" https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df0248cb-612f-4e2f-9665-11c68c401458/this-is-how-to-call-win32-api-calls-in-vbscript-and-jscript-sample-windows-api-functions?forum=scripting

Comment: Reviewing the logs I have just found what went wrong, even though I got a .dll file, this method also required admin privileges to register it. On execution of regasm /codebase  I got the following message. RegAsm : error RA0000 : An error occurred while writing the registration informa
tion to the registry. Administrator permissions are needed to use the selected o
ptions. Use an administrator command prompt to complete these tasks.

Comment: Is there a way to call wso.dll, in any way, from vbscript, without registering it as an activex for the entire system ?

Comment: Just tried, didn't work, perhaps the created wso.dll isn't the same kind of dll that this application expects. The error message follows RegSvrEx.exe /c wso.dll
Error occured registering server - The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: Then I suppose you're out of luck.

Comment: I also tried the CCRP registration utility, however it also fails with the following error. "The DLLRegisterServer entry point was not found in wso.dll". Yep, I'm boned !

Comment: IMO, don't use VB6 to start new project development